# How to find the lower eyelid in an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image of 480x360 px that contains eye portion only i.e., sclera iris, pupil, eyebrows  etc. Now I have to find the lower eyelid in the image.

What I've done till now is that cut the image in 2 parts upper and lower half. Now apply edge detector (Canny) on lower part and then parabola fitting on the resultant image.

I am getting ok results but eyelid is not parabola so sometimes  the parabola goes into the sclera region also.

I am thinking to doing curve fitting but a better idea looks like funding a curved line in the edge map.

Can you help in finding the curved line in the edge map ?

Comment: Do you have any example images showing the problem and your current solution & results?

Comment: You should look into "Template Matchig" Its a machine learning skill that would be used for this.

Comment: You could try to perform smoothing B-spline fitting

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in [this paper](http://eprints.sztaki.hu/7986/)¹ that deals with eyelid contour approximation. It should help you out.

¹ Pernek, Ákos and Hajder, Levente (2014) Precise 3D Pose Estimation of Human Faces. In: VISAPP 2014. Proceedings of the 9th International Conference on Computer Vision Theory and Applications. Vol. 3. SciTePress, Lisszabon, pp. 618-625. ISBN 978-989-758-005-5

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but if you could explain a bit more about what's in the link that'd be good. *.SE sites tend to not like link-only answers.

Comment: Unlike most other people on *.SE I find link-only answers not as bad (hey, let's harvest the power of this new hypertext thingie on the intertubes!), but consider it crucial to make it easy to re-find the source e.g. on archive.org; in this case, it's even a Paper, so adding the full citation seems a no-brainer :)

Comment: Thanks @MarcusMüller : The reason link-only answers are bad is that it makes it nearly impossible to find the information once the link dies.  Adding additional information (like the full citation you've added) means I can search for $that$ instead and actually find the information linked to rather than a 404 error.